# How can I execute a Concourse task script from another resource's directory?

Tags: concourse, concourse-task

Having this task configuration:

```
config:
  platform: linux
  inputs:
    - name: resource_to_run_in
    - name: resource_with_scripts
  run:
    path: resource_with_scripts/script.sh
    dir: resource_to_run_in
```

I get the following error:

```
Backend error: Exit status: 500, message: {"Type":"ExecutableNotFoundError","Message":"exec failed: container_linux.go:344: starting container process caused \"exec: \\\"resource_with_scripts/script.sh\\\": stat resource_with_scripts/script.sh: no such file or directory\"\n","Handle":"","ProcessID":"","Binary":""}
```

I was expecting Concourse to run the absolute path of `script.sh` in the directory of the resource `resource_to_run_in`.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

The only way I found is to use dot-navigation:

```
config:
  platform: linux
  inputs:
    - name: resource_to_run_in
    - name: resource_with_scripts
  run:
    path: ../resource_with_scripts/script.sh
    dir: resource_to_run_in
```

This way it works, still I wish Concourse would resolve these resource names to absolute paths at runtime (without displaying them to the user)